# object moves only one way in my pygame codes, how can i solve this?

Tags: python, pygame

i was making little shooting game and i tested if character moves well.

and there's 'angle' property of 'james' object of 'hero' class to move character to any place of particular distance.

but although very obvious angle changing code, it goes to one angle i gave when i made that object
and it didn't produce any error

it seems one of code related movement didn't work right. it's every part of my code to move objects

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    '''some other codes'''
    elif event.type==KEYDOWN:
        if not event.key in keys:
            keys.append(event.key)
    elif event.type==KEYUP:
        keys.remove(event.key)

class moving_man():
    def __init__(self,hp,speed,angle,
             s_angle,rect,weapon): #체력 ,이동속도 ,움직이는 각도 ,사격 각도 ,크기및 위치 ,패턴 ,무기
        self.hp=hp
        self.speed=speed
        self.rect=rect
        self.angle=angle
        self.s_angle=s_angle
        self.weapon=weapon 
    def move(self): #움직이기
        self.rect.centerx+=math.cos(self.angle)*self.speed
        self.rect.centery-=math.sin(self.angle)*self.speed
    '''some other codes'''

class hero(moving_man):
    def __init__(self,hp,speed,angle,
             s_angle,rect,weapon):
        super().__init__(hp,speed,angle,
             s_angle,rect,weapon)
    def pattern(self): 
        if len(keys)==1:
            if keys[0]==K_w:
                self.angle=math.radians(90)
            elif keys[0]==K_a:
                self.angle=math.radians(180)
            elif keys[0]==K_s:
                self.angle=math.radians(270)
            elif keys[0]==K_d:
                self.angle=math.radians(0)
            self.move()
        elif len(keys)>=2:
            if K_w and K_a in keys[:2]:
                self.angle=math.radians(135)
            elif K_a and K_s in keys[:2]:
                self.angle=math.radians(225)
            elif K_s and K_d in keys[:2]:
                self.angle=math.radians(315)
            elif K_d and K_w in keys[:2]:
                self.angle=math.radians(45)
            self.move()
```

Comment: it has to be `if K_w in keys[:2] and K_a in keys[:2]:`

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea why i have took 3 days to figure out simple mistake that i had pressed wrong button to move my character for **3 days**.

my codes save every key pressed but change angle to go only when i press w,a,s,d key
so if i press the others, key is saved in 'keys' list and still move the character.
but it goes only by the temporary angle i gave when i made that object because codes didnt change the angle